# Responsive table with clickable pictures

Tags: html, html-table

I am trying to create a simple website for indexing webcameras. Most of the sites or software I know of only shows you a couple of images at a time. Want I want to do is to display many cams as a "grid", which adjusts to your current screen size (mainly 1080p). Next, I would like to be able to click the image from the camera and make the image full screen, or center at least.

This is for use in a surveillance situation. Any scripts, wordpressthemes or similar solutions would also be considered.

Anyone know how this could be done?

This is my code so far:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<html>
<style>
th {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}

table {
    margin: 0px auto;            
}​

</style>
<table>
<table style="margin: 0px auto; height: 200px;" border="100" width="1002"       cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<body style="background-color:#000000">
<tr>
<th>Bodø småbåthavn</th>
<th>Moskenes</th>
<th>Sortland Havn Sør</th>
<th>Sortland Havn Sør/Øst</th>
<th>Ankenes båthavn</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="http://193.201.74.114/mjpg/video.mjpg" alt="Bodø Småbåthavn" width="350" height="300" /></td>
<td><img src="http://www.lofotposten.no/static/local/webcam/moskenes.jpg" alt="Moskenes" width="350" height="300" /></td>
<td><img src="http://sortland-havn.no/webcamera/havnnord.jpg" alt="Sortland Sør" width="350" height="300" /></td>
<td><img src="http://sortland-havn.no/webcamera/havnsor.jpg" alt="Sortland Sør/Øst" width="350" height="300" /></td>
<td><img src="http://ankenes.dyndns.org/jpg/image.jpg" alt="Ankenes båthavn" width="350" height="300" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Tromsø Havn kamera 1</th>
<th>Tromsø Havn kamera 2</th>
<th>Tromsø Havn kamera 3</th>
<th>Senja Havn</th>
<th>Skjervøy Havn</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="http://www.tromso.havn.no/uploads/img/webcams/0.jpg" alt="Tromsø Havn kamera 1" width="350" height="300" /></td>
<td><img src="http://www.tromso.havn.no/uploads/img/webcams/1.jpg" alt="Tromsø Havn kamera 2" width="350" height="300" /></td>
<td><img src="http://www.tromso.havn.no/uploads/img/webcams/2.jpg" alt="Tromsø" width="350" height="300" /></td>
<td><img src="http://images.webcams.travel/webcam/1323784937-Weather-Hamn-i-Senja%2C-Northern-Norway-Visit-The-Arctic-Hamn.jpg" alt="Senja Havn" width="350" height="300" /></td>
<td><img src="http://www.arcticutleie.no/webkamera.jpg" alt="Skjervøy" width="350" height="300" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Honningsvåg Havn</th>
<th>Honningsvåg fra Elvedalen</th>
<th>Honningsvåg fra Fagskolen</th>
<th>Berlevåg</th>
<th>Båtsfjord</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="http://213.161.172.115/jpg/image.jpg" alt="Honningsvåg Havn" width="350" height="300" /></td>
<td><img src="http://vaer.visto.no/elvstor.jpg" alt="Honningsvåg fra Elvedalen" width="350" height="300" /></td>
<td><img src="http://hvg.axiscam.net/jpg/image.jpg" alt="Honningsvåg fra Fagskolen" width="350" height="300" /></td>
<td><img src="http://62.63.28.98/jpg/image.jpg" alt="Berlevåg Havn" width="350" height="300" /></td>
<td><img src="http://185.36.212.175/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=CIF&amp;dummy=1425475415542" alt="Båtsfjord" width="350" height="300" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to step away from tables and use a flexible grid layout based on the [flexbox model](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) from *CSS-Tricks*.

As for the full size images: any "lightbox" plugin based on jQuery will suffice.